# Understanding how observables work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic2 and I have created a service that returns bunch of json data but I am having trouble understanding the "concept".

I have

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class PlaceService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getPlaces()
{ 
  let url = '/api/43.009953/-81.273613/b502daab-2c7b-4cea-a00e-dc5aa6b58196';
  return this.http.get(url).map(res=>res.json())

}

getPlace()
{
  let url = '/api/getplace/b502daab-2c7b-4cea-a00e-dc5aa6b58196/6';
  return this.http.get(url).map(res=>res.json())

}

}
```

I understand both of my functions return Obserables but when I try to use them in a page thats where things get weird for me.

here is the code using it in the .ts of a page

```
public placeName:string;
public place:any;
public amenities: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
public placeService: PlaceService, 
public navParams: NavParams,
public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {

  let placeId = navParams.get("placeId");

  placeService.getPlace().subscribe(data=>{
     this.place = data.Place;
     this.placeName = this.place.Name;
     this.amenities= data.Amenities;
     console.log(this.amenities);
  });

}
```

As you can see i have this.place =data.Place which is a json object with flat properties and collections properties.

It seems for every flat property i have that comes from my observable, I have to create a property in my page ts in order to be able to access it in the html. For example this.placeName = this.place.Name

Why cant I have one object that is my whole json object(flat and collection properties) and reference it like this in my page

{{place.Name}}

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You should be able to push only ONE object to the template and access its properties as deep as you want. What do you see when you `console.log(data)` inside your subscribe()? Also, what do you see if you do `this.data = data` and then interpolate data in your template `<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>`?

Comment: when i display the object to console it is the correct json object with all properties, when i access it from the page, {{place.Name}} it says "Name" property is not found

Comment: if i do {{place?.Name}} then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually.. assign it only to a field and continue using that field in your template. For example:

```
  placeService.getPlace().subscribe(data=>{
     this.data = data;
  });
```

**example template:**

```
<div>
    <p>{{data?.Place}}</p>
    <p>{{data?.Place?.name}}</p>
    <p>{{data?.Amenities}}</p>
</div>
```

Note: The safe navigation operator "`?`" is useful for async data. It means when `data` is not `null` execute `data.Place`

Comment: it seems that I needed the ?  why do i need this? does that mean that property is not "called" yet?

Comment: @Zoinky as I've said since observables work asynchronously `this.data` will be `undefined` until it gets the `data` and `?` Does a `null`/`undefined` check until then